# Android sending commands via bluetooth failed

Tags: android, bluetooth, command

I have been trying to connect to the MCU motherboard NOT using arduino to code, embedded with the Bluetooth ICU chips HC-06. I have successfully got good connection between my android device to the board. After that ,  I try to send  "26 24 54 02 c9 00" as pure string. But, after for a long time, there is no response from the device.  I have even checked with the AT command s to sent such as AT+NAMExyz , and AT. There is still no response from the device. Would you please tell me is there another any way out ? What else programming work I have to do besides onto Android devices? If I am not using the Arduino device to connected with,What else I have to observe and conduct the research? The below is my code.

The below is my logcat message

```
07-29 16:45:50.701: D/dalvikvm(26944): Late-enabling CheckJNI
07-29 16:45:50.721: I/dalvikvm(26944): Enabling JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 7...
07-29 16:45:53.501: D/BluetoothCommandService(26944): start
07-29 16:45:53.501: D/BluetoothCommandService(26944): setState() 0 -> 1
07-29 16:45:55.361: D/dalvikvm(26944): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 100K, 1% free 17103K/17236K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
07-29 16:46:04.211: D/BluetoothCommandService(26944): connect to: 00:14:01:22:18:12
07-29 16:46:04.211: D/BluetoothCommandService(26944): setState() 1 -> 2
07-29 16:46:04.211: I/BluetoothCommandService(26944): BEGIN mConnectThread
07-29 16:46:04.211: W/BluetoothAdapter(26944): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
07-29 16:46:04.211: D/BluetoothSocket(26944): connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[53]}
07-29 16:46:06.241: D/BluetoothCommandService(26944): connected
07-29 16:46:06.241: D/BluetoothCommandService(26944): create ConnectedThread
07-29 16:46:06.241: I/BluetoothCommandService(26944): BEGIN mConnectedThread
07-29 16:46:06.241: D/BluetoothCommandService(26944): setState() 2 -> 3
07-29 16:46:09.851: D/commmand(26944): &$R\x00\xc9
07-29 16:46:13.241: D/commmand(26944): &$R\x00\xc9
07-29 16:46:19.581: D/commmand(26944): &$V\x00\xcd
07-29 16:46:39.811: D/dalvikvm(26944): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
07-29 16:46:39.871: D/dalvikvm(26944): GC_CONCURRENT freed 48K, 1% free 17522K/17616K, paused 6ms+1ms, total 57ms
07-29 16:47:23.631: D/commmand(26944): &$R\x00\xc9
07-29 16:47:24.911: D/commmand(26944): &$R\x00\xc9
07-29 16:47:25.651: D/commmand(26944): &$R\x00\xc9
07-29 16:47:26.401: D/commmand(26944): &$V\x00\xcd
07-29 16:47:26.961: D/commmand(26944): &$R\x00\xc9
07-29 16:47:27.771: D/commmand(26944): &$R\x00\xc9
07-29 16:47:28.601: D/commmand(26944): &$R\x00\xc9
07-29 16:47:35.171: D/commmand(26944): &$R\x00\xc9
07-29 16:47:35.991: D/commmand(26944): &$R\x00\xc9
07-29 16:47:36.441: D/commmand(26944): &$R\x00\xc9
07-29 16:47:37.141: D/commmand(26944): &$V\x00\xcd
07-29 16:47:37.921: D/commmand(26944): &$V\x00\xcd
07-29 16:47:38.281: D/commmand(26944): &$V\x00\xcd
07-29 16:47:38.581: D/commmand(26944): &$V\x00\xcd
07-29 16:47:40.001: D/commmand(26944): &$R\x00\xc9




    package com.example.android.BluetoothChat;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.util.UUID;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.ToggleButton;
```

CUrrent:

The below is my code:

BluetoothCommandService.java

```
 public class BluetoothCommandService {
        private static final String TAG = "BluetoothCommandService";
        private static final boolean D = true;

        private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    // Member fields
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private int mState;
    //    private BluetoothDevice mSavedDevice;
    //    private int mConnectionLostCount;

    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

    // Constants that indicate command to computer
    public static final int EXIT_CMD = -1;
    public static final int VOL_UP = 1;
    public static final int VOL_DOWN = 2;
    public static final int MOUSE_MOVE = 3;
    public static Context ctx ;
    /**
     * Constructor. Prepares a new BluetoothChat session.
     * @param context  The UI Activity Context
     * @param handler  A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
     */
    public BluetoothCommandService(Context context, Handler handler) {
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mState = STATE_NONE;
        //mConnectionLostCount = 0;
        ctx = context;
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
        mState = state;

        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mHandler.obtainMessage(RemoteBluetooth.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
    }

    /**
     * Return the current connection state. */
    public synchronized int getState() {
        return mState;
    }

    /**
     * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume() */
    public synchronized void start() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
    }
    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

        if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
        }

        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }
    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connected");

        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}
mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(RemoteBluetooth.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(RemoteBluetooth.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);


        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }

    /**
     * Stop all threads
     */
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "stop");
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        setState(STATE_NONE);
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     * @param out The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        ConnectedThread r;

        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }

        r.write(out);
    }

    public void write(int out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionFailed() {
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);

        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(RemoteBluetooth.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(RemoteBluetooth.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionLost() {

        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(RemoteBluetooth.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(RemoteBluetooth.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
       }
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
            setName("ConnectThread");

            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {

                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                connectionFailed();
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
                }
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothCommandService.this.start();
                return;
            }

            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            synchronized (BluetoothCommandService.this) {
                mConnectThread = null;
            }

            // Start the connected thread
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static String slurp(final InputStream is, final int bufferSize)
    {
        final char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
        final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            final Reader in = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
            try {
                for (;;) {
                    int rsz = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                    if (rsz < 0)
                        break;
                    out.append(buffer, 0, rsz);
                }
            }
            finally {
                in.close();
            }
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            /* ... */
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            /* ... */
        }
        return out.toString();
    }
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            while (true) {
                try {
                    int bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    Log.d( "message" , slurp(mmInStream, 1024));
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, slurp(mmInStream, 1024), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(RemoteBluetooth.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void write(int out) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(out);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(EXIT_CMD);
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RemoteBluetooth.java

```
public class RemoteBluetooth extends Activity {

    private TextView mTitle;

    // Intent request codes
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;

    // Message types sent from the BluetoothChatService Handler
    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;

    public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
    public static final String TOAST = "toast";

    private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothCommandService mCommandService = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);

        mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_left_text);
        mTitle.setText(R.string.app_name);
        mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_right_text);

        // Get local Bluetooth adapter
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
        // setupCommand() will then be called during onActivityResult
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
        // otherwise set up the command service
        else {
            if (mCommandService==null)
                setupCommand();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mCommandService != null) {
            if (mCommandService.getState() == BluetoothCommandService.STATE_NONE) {
                mCommandService.start();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupCommand() {
        mCommandService = new BluetoothCommandService(this, mHandler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mCommandService != null)
            mCommandService.stop();
    }

    private void ensureDiscoverable() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() !=
                BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
            Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
            startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        }
    }

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                case BluetoothCommandService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connected_to);
                    mTitle.append("HC-06");
                    break;
                case BluetoothCommandService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connecting);
                    break;
                case BluetoothCommandService.STATE_LISTEN:
                case BluetoothCommandService.STATE_NONE:
                    mTitle.setText(R.string.title_not_connected);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                        + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the device MAC address
                String address = data.getExtras()
                        .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
                // Get the BLuetoothDevice object
                BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(address);
                // Attempt to connect to the device
                mCommandService.connect(device);
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                setupCommand();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.scan:
        Intent serverIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
            return true;
        case R.id.discoverable:
        ensureDiscoverable();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static String hexadecimal(String input, String charsetName) 
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        if (input == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        return asHex(input.getBytes(charsetName));
    }

    private static final char[] HEX_CHARS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

    public static String asHex(byte[] buf)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[2 * buf.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; ++i)
        {
            chars[2 * i] = HEX_CHARS[(buf[i] & 0xF0) >>> 4];
            chars[2 * i + 1] = HEX_CHARS[buf[i] & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(chars);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {

            try{
                String syncCommand = "&$";
                String descriptor = "R";
                int datalength = 0;
                String data = "";
                if(datalength > 0 ){
                    String data1 = hexadecimal(String.valueOf(datalength)  , "UTF-8");
                    String data2 = hexadecimal(String.valueOf(data)  , "UTF-8");
                    data = data1 + data2;
                }else{
                    data =  "\\x00" ;
                }
                int checksum = 0x77; 
                String  descHex =   hexadecimal(String.valueOf(descriptor)  , "UTF-8");    
                checksum +=  ( Integer.parseInt(descHex,16)    );
                String checkSumString = "\\x" +  Integer.toHexString(checksum);                 
                String fullCommand = syncCommand +  descriptor + data + checkSumString;

                Log.d("commmand" , fullCommand);

                mCommandService.write(fullCommand.getBytes());

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return true;
    }
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
        try{
            String syncCommand = "&$";
            String descriptor = "V";
            int datalength = 0;
            String data = "";
            if(datalength > 0 ){
                String data1 = hexadecimal(String.valueOf(datalength)  , "UTF-8");
                String data2 = hexadecimal(String.valueOf(data)  , "UTF-8");
                data = data1 + data2;
            }else{
                data =  "\\x00" ;
            }
            int checksum = 0x77; 
            String  descHex =   hexadecimal(String.valueOf(descriptor)  , "UTF-8");
        //  String  dataHex = datalength == 0 ? "\\x00" : hexadecimal(String.valueOf(datalength)  , "UTF-8");
        //  Log.d("descHex" , descHex);
        //  Log.d("dataHex" , dataHex);

            checksum +=  ( Integer.parseInt(descHex,16)  );

            String checkSumString = "\\x" +  Integer.toHexString(checksum);

            String fullCommand = syncCommand +  descriptor + data + checkSumString;
            Log.d("commmand" , fullCommand);
            mCommandService.write(fullCommand.getBytes());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Original one:

```
public class BluetoothChat extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        Button Connect;
        ToggleButton OnOff;
        TextView Result;
        private String dataToSend;

        private static final String TAG = "Jon";
        private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
        private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
        private OutputStream outStream = null;
        private static String address = "00:1a:a1:22:11:12";
        private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID
                .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
        private InputStream inStream = null;
        Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        byte delimiter = 100;
        boolean stopWorker = false;
        int readBufferPosition = 0;
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.conne

ct);
        OnOff = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tgOnOff);
        Result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgJonduino);

        Connect.setOnClickListener(this);
        OnOff.setOnClickListener(this);

        CheckBt();
        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        Log.e("Jon", device.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View control) {
        switch (control.getId()) {
        case R.id.connect:
            Connect();
            break;
        case R.id.tgOnOff:
            if (OnOff.isChecked()) {
                dataToSend = "26 24 54 02 c9 00";
                Log.e("JonS", dataToSend);
                writeData(dataToSend);
            } else if (!OnOff.isChecked()) {
                dataToSend = "26245200c900";
                Log.e("JonS", dataToSend);
                writeData(dataToSend);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    private void resetConnection() {
    //  setState(STATE_NONE);
        Log.d(TAG, "reset connection");
        if (inStream != null) {
            try {
                inStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG,"exception in closing inputstream - " + e.getMessage());
            }
            inStream = null;
        }
        if (outStream != null) {
            try {
                outStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG,"exception in closing outputstream - " + e.getMessage());
            }
            outStream = null;
        }
        if (btSocket != null) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG,"exception in closing socket - " + e.getMessage());
            }
            btSocket = null;
        }
        Connect();
    }

    private void CheckBt() {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Disabled !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Bluetooth null !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    public void Connect() {
        Log.d(TAG, address);
        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to ... " + device);
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        try {
            btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            btSocket.connect();
            Log.d(TAG, "Connection made.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Unable to end the connection");
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Socket creation failed");
        }

        beginListenForData();
    }

    private void writeData(String data) {
        try {
            outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "Bug BEFORE Sending stuff", e);
        }

        String message = data;
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

        try {
            outStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "Bug while sending stuff", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        try {
            if(btSocket!=null){
                btSocket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void beginListenForData()   {
        try {
            inStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Thread workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {                
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        int bytesAvailable = inStream.available();                        
                        if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                        {
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            inStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                            {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if(b == delimiter)
                                {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                    //US-ASCII
                                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "UTF-8");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;
                                    handler.post(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        public void run()
                                        {

                                            if(Result.getText().toString().equals("..")) {
                                                Result.setText(data);
                                            } else {
                                                Result.append("\n"+data);
                                            }

                                            /* You also can use Result.setText(data); it won't display multilines
                                             */

                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (IOException ex) 
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        workerThread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the MCU device used? I've been using the HC-06 without problems... And as far as I can see, there's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: I also use HC-06 .

The above is my modified code

Comment: Did you check the MCU's led blinking frequency after the connection is made? If it is blinking at 2Hz, then the pairing wasn't completed. After the connection, it should show a double flicker per second.

Comment: After the connection is made, the LED lights up without blinking

Comment: The pairing process is done by inserting the secret code , say 1234 , 0000

Comment: And it shows the response message after pressing back button to exit the program. How should I read the message on real time ?

Comment: Instead of executing the Runnable that updates the UI inside the post method of a Handler, try to run it using the following method from the Acitivy class: void runOnUiThread (Runnable action)

Comment: I have been already using Handler in seperate service class. how should i pass the message on real time to thew Main UI elements  ?

Comment: I have been used handleMessage to get messages from BluetoothChatService but the message only shows after the activity has been ended. How should i  modify ?

Comment: You can use my Bluetooth Application on github as a guide. Its functional and similar to yours. Particularly look at the Bluetooth Class. https://github.com/kamilagrawala/IntellicycleV2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the logs seems Pairing and connection establishment to the remote device is successful.To debug further why application is not receiving the data you need to find whether response from remote device is receiving at Bluetooth Stack and then sending it to application. For this you need to capture snoop logs.On JB and later versions it will found under /sdcard/btsnoop_hci.log after enabling in setting.